# Reading file in bash loop on AIX/bash is much slower than in Linux/ksh - BLOCKSIZE?

Tags: linux, bash, performance, aix

We have a custom script ( in ksh) which was developed in RHEL Linux.
The functionality is
1) Read the input ASCII file
2) Replace "\" with "\\" using sed -i inplace the files
3) Load the history file into memory
4) Compare the data with current day 
5) Generate the net change records

During a platform upgrade, we had to migrate this script on AIX 7.1 and
replaced the ksh with bash since, typeset -A is not available on ksh AIX and sed -i command with perl -pi -e and the rest of the script is almost the same.

We observe that the script processes for 1 hour ( 691 files) in Linux but, in AIX it is taking 7+ hours for the same.

We observe for one input file the below snippet is having a performance difference, Linux code completes within 1-2 seconds whereas, in AIX it takes 13-15 seconds. Due to this performance difference for each file , for 691 files, the script is taking 7 hours to complete.

Could you please help me understand if we can tune this script for a better performance on AIX. Any pointers will be very helpful.
Thank you in advance for your help!

Adding test results below for more precise issue

### Linux Test script:

```
#!/bin/sh
export LANG="C"
echo `date`
typeset -A Archive_Lines
if [ -f "8249cii1.ASC" ]
then
echo `date` Starting sed
sed -i 's/\\/\\\\/g' 1577cii1.ASC
echo `date` Ending sed
while read line; do
 if [[ "${#line}" == "401" ]]
 then
 Archive_Lines["${line:0:19}""${line:27}"]="${line:27:10}"
else
echo ${#line}
fi
done < 1577cii1.ASC
echo `date` Starting sed
sed -i 's/\\\\/\\/g' 1577cii1.ASC
echo `date` Ending sed
fi
echo `date`
```

### Linux execution:

```
ksh read4.sh
Sun Nov 12 15:03:18 CST 2017
Sun Nov 12 15:03:18 CST 2017 Starting sed
Sun Nov 12 15:03:19 CST 2017 Ending sed
402
405
403
339
403
403
Sun Nov 12 15:03:22 CST 2017 Starting sed
Sun Nov 12 15:03:23 CST 2017 Ending sed
Sun Nov 12 15:03:23 CST 2017
```

### AIX Test Script:

```
#!/usr/bin/bash
export LANG="C"
echo `date`
typeset -A Archive_Lines
if [ -f "1577cii1.ASC" ]
then
echo `date` Starting perl
perl -pi -e 's/\\/\\\\/g' 1577cii1.ASC
echo `date` Ending perl
while read line; do
 if [[ "${#line}" == "401" ]]
 then
 Archive_Lines["${line:0:19}""${line:27}"]="${line:27:10}"
else
echo ${#line}
 fi
done < 1577cii1.ASC
echo `date` Starting perl
perl -pi -e 's/\\\\/\\/g' 1577cii1.ASC
echo `date` Ending perl
fi
echo `date`
```

### AIX Test execution:

```
  bash read_test.sh
    Sun Nov 12 15:00:17 CST 2017
    Sun Nov 12 15:00:17 CST 2017 Starting perl
    Sun Nov 12 15:00:18 CST 2017 Ending perl
    402
    405
    313
    403
    337
    403
    403
    Sun Nov 12 15:01:29 CST 2017 Starting perl
    Sun Nov 12 15:01:29 CST 2017 Ending perl
    Sun Nov 12 15:01:29 CST 2017
```

Replacing Archive_Lines["${line:0:19}""${line:27}"]="${line:27:10}" with echo"."

```
 bash read_test.sh
Sun Nov 12 16:56:27 CST 2017
Sun Nov 12 16:56:27 CST 2017 Starting perl
Sun Nov 12 16:56:27 CST 2017 Ending perl
.
.
.
.
.
Sun Nov 12 16:56:42 CST 2017 Starting perl
Sun Nov 12 16:56:42 CST 2017 Ending perl
Sun Nov 12 16:56:42 CST 2017
```

With Archive_Lines["${line:0:19}""${line:27}"]="${line:27:10}"

```
 bash read_test.sh
Sun Nov 12 16:59:52 CST 2017
Sun Nov 12 16:59:52 CST 2017 Starting perl
Sun Nov 12 16:59:52 CST 2017 Ending perl
402
405
313
403
337
403
403
Sun Nov 12 17:01:11 CST 2017 Starting perl
Sun Nov 12 17:01:11 CST 2017 Ending perl
Sun Nov 12 17:01:11 CST 2017
```

Thanks,
Vamsi

Comment: Is there a single part that is 'noticeably' slower? Also, it might be worthwhile to replace the script wholesale (with, eg, perl).

Comment: Working code should be posted for optimization on [Code Review](https://codereview.stackexchange.com) instead.

Comment: @user2864740 - During my test runs I see the while loop of reading lines and loading into associative arrays for comparison is causing the difference.  Some people suggested BLOCKSIZE parameter but, I was not able to identify how to check this variable and modify on AIX or Linux.

Comment: @LW001 Sure, thank you I can only be able to post after 40 min

Comment: for `typeset -A` support in `ksh`, consider switching to `ksh93` (I make extensive use of `typeset -A` on AIX by using `ksh93`);

Comment: @markp - I tried to use the below command for typeset -A "ksh93 typeset -A ArchiveLines" but, the below command fails  Archive_Lines["${line:0:19}""${line:27}"]="${line:27:10}" saying bad substitution

Comment: did you make that typo with the underscore (ArchiveLines vs Archive_Lines) in your test? issue `ksh93` by itself; at the new command prompt issue `typeset -A Archive_Lines`, then run a simple test like: `Archive_Lines["abc"]="def"`

Comment: Number of lines in the 2 files (8249cii1.ASC, 1577cii1.ASC) used for your timing tests? (especially since final results show different set of `echo ${#line}`)

Comment: I might be checking the wrong 8249 using if -f but, the inputs for both the scripts is the same file. It is just that on AIX there is a special character on line 313 causing it to be displayed in output. We can consider this is apples to apples comparison.

Comment: Try isolating the difference. Will you still see a difference when you replace `Archive_Lines["${line:0:19}""${line:27}"]="${line:27:10}"` with `echo "."`?

Comment: @WalterA: I replaced the line with echo "." and added the test results to the post. Looks like there is difference.

Comment: if the latest test (replacing substrings with `echo "."`) generated a lot of ouput, I'd recommend replacing `echo "."` with `x=1`; the objective is to eliminate the output of a large number of rows, which in turn should eliminate the overhead/time required to display/scroll the lines across your terminal (which could be skewing your timings); objective is to find out if `bash's` length test is causing any excessive timings

Comment: @markp: Thank you for the clarification.Yes, replacing with x=1 did show the difference and we can now isolate that the bash's length test is not causing excessive timing. It is the insert into Associative array which is causing the difference.   I also tried the awk functionality below but, looks like the performance time is increased with it.

Comment: the only other ideas I can think of (at this time) ... remove the row with the funky character to see if that makes any difference ... run some tests with ksh93 and/or a different AIX machine ... have your admin review your version of bash (old/outdated?)

Answer (score 2):

As Walter had suggested, it looks like there are some performance hits in `bash` for the substring processing (and possibly the length test).

It might be of interest to see what kind of timings you get with other solutions.

Here's a simplistic `awk` solution that should do the same thing as the original bash/substring logic (using your current sample data file; sans the output of line lengths != 401):

```
awk 'length($0)==401 { print substr($0,1,20)substr($0,28)"|"substr($0,28,10) }' 1577cii1.ASC | \
while IFS="|" read idx val
do
    Archive_Lines["${idx}"]="${val}"
done
```

- `length($0)==401` : if line length is 401 then ...
- `print ...."|" ...` : print 2 sections of output/fields separated by a pipe (`|`), where the fields are ...
- `substr($0,1,20)substr($0,28)` : equivalent to your ${line:0:19}${line:27}
- `substr($0,28,10)` : equivalent to your ${line:27:10}
- at this point every line of length 401 is generating output like `string1|string2`
- `while IFS="|" read idx val` : split the input back out into 2 variables ...
- `Archive_Lines["${idx}"]="${val}"` : use the 2 variables as the array index/value pairs

NOTE: The addition of the pipe (`|`) as a field separator was added in case your substrings could include spaces; and of course if your substrings could include the pipe (`|`) then replace with some other character that won't show up in your substrings and which you can use as a field delimiter.

The objective is to see if `awk's` built-in length/substring processing is faster than `bash's` length/substring processing ...

Answer (score 1):

This solved my problem

```
#!/usr/bin/ksh93
export LANG="C"
echo `date`
typeset -A Archive_Lines
if [ -f "1577cii1.ASC" ]
then
echo `date` Starting perl
perl -pi -e 's/\\/\\\\/g' 1577cii1.ASC
echo `date` Ending perl
while read line; do
 if [[ "${#line}" == "401" ]]
 then
Archive_Lines[${line:0:19}${line:27}]="${line:27:10}"
else
echo ${#line}
 fi
done < 1577cii1.ASC
echo `date` Starting perl
perl -pi -e 's/\\\\/\\/g' 1577cii1.ASC
echo `date` Ending perl
fi
echo `date`


ksh93 read_test3.sh
Sun Nov 12 19:19:34 CST 2017
Sun Nov 12 19:19:34 CST 2017 Starting perl
Sun Nov 12 19:19:34 CST 2017 Ending perl
402
405
403
339
403
403
Sun Nov 12 19:19:38 CST 2017 Starting perl
Sun Nov 12 19:19:39 CST 2017 Ending perl
Sun Nov 12 19:19:39 CST 2017
```

Comment: hmmm, so it was 'just' a case of switching to `ksh93`?  if so, sounds like your AIX admin needs to track down a potential issue with your bash version eh ...

Comment: @markp: Yeah,looks like ksh gives better performance with associative arrays than bash as it only accepts numeric indexes and may be it is slow to process. Anyhow, my problem is solved ! Thank you one and all who helped me in this process.

Comment: Please add some notes to the answer to identify "what exactly" solved the problem - it'll make the answer more useful in the future.